# why does myeclipse console have no output?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, java-native-interface

I use JNI　to call dll on windows.

My java code is as following.
[image: java code]

My debug information is here .
[image: debug image]

Add I see that the info is not null.But why console only outputs dddd without anything else .

Help ,please.

Comment: Why not tell us what the native code does or better yet show us?  Maybe you are closing stdout? Maybe there is a bug in the native code?

Comment: @ChuckFricano In the dll ,I've used file input and ouput.And when file operation is over , I closed it.In case it matters,I write" freopen( "CON ",   "w",   stdout); " in the end of function run.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout);
```

to try and undo something like

```
freopen( "myStdOut.log", "a", stdout);
```

is not going to work in EIDE. Remove

```
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout);
```

and if you are doing

```
freopen( "myStdOut.log", "a", stdout);
```

remove that too.

Comment: Hey,thx. I do as you say .I removed "freopen ..." and the console has output now. But if I want to redirect console output in dll,how can I do it if I dont use freopen ..?

Comment: I don't know the full details of what it is you are trying to do.  Post another question for redirecting console in a DLL and include your JNI code and complete description of the problem.